# Pandas rolling sum on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe configured in the following structure:

```
   date  amount  another_amount  name
0   1/1       5               6  dave
1   2/1       3               4  dave
...
2  12/1       7              10  dave
```

How can I sum the previous row value for amount and another_amount until the last row will have the sum of the entire dataframe?

So for example the 2/1 row will have 8 (5+3) for amount and 10 (6+4) for another_amount, then the 3/1 row would have whatever that row contained plus the previous sum of 8 and 10 in their respective columns

I apologize if this a confusing question I will try to clarify as much as possible

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
df.iloc[:, 1:-1] = df.iloc[:, 1:-1].cumsum()

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   date  amount  another_amount  name
0   1/1       5               6  dave
1   2/1       8              10  dave
2  12/1      15              20  dave
```

Or if you only want `amount` and `another_amount`:

```
df.loc[:, ['amount', 'another_amount']] = df.loc[:, ['amount', 'another_amount']].cumsum()
```

Comment: Hey this is actually what I was looking for, however it doesnt keep the date and name columns. Anyway to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't keep the date and name columns? You could copy the dataframe and use any of the above suggestions.

Comment: Yea sorry I think I figured it out, marked it as right!

Answer (score -1):

You are probably looking for [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html).

Comment: Word of advice, you may want to put more effort into answering the question.